# Should I run multiple interaction terms in a single model or in separate models?

Tags: r, regression, survey

I am new to statistical survey analysis and I'm using R. We have ran a pre-test with a very small sample (n=50). Our respondents were sorted into two treatment groups (T1 and T2 - basically treatment and control). We also had the respondents answer a Yes/No (coded 1,0) Question before treatment (Q1). We are interested in the different effect of each of four different interactions:
(1) T1=1 * Q1=1
(2) T2=1 * Q1=1
(3) T2=0 * Q1=0
(4) T1=0 * Q1=0

On the outcome variable: DV1 (a continuous variable)

Does it make sense to run a regression with all four interactions in the same model:

reg<-lm(DV1~(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+ controls) where each number here is an interaction, or should I examine the effects of each interaction term on the outcome separately?

I hope this makes sense!

Thank you!

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your interaction variables nor I do understand what is the aim of your research question.

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear! We're interested in looking at the interaction between first and second order beliefs on an outcome variable. The treatment is a second order belief, while we're testing for first order beliefs in the first Q in the survey (before being sorted into treatments), so we're sort of interested in the interactive effect for four combinations on the outcome.

Comment: Sorry, but I share @utobi 's confusion, even after your reply. This is not how interactions are usually written. The usual way is to write them as products of two variables.  I'm not entirely sure that you  even have two variables, you've only listed one. 

For example, if you were interested in predicting someone's income based on age, sex and the interaction, you would write:

Income = f(age + sex + age*sex)

If you do have two IVs, each with two levels, then this will automatically do what you want (which is, essentially, test ONE interaction).